# Classes and id's from css

Tags: css, eclipse

How can i get classes and id's at html file from css using content assist?
Using:
Eclipse IDE for JavaScript Web Developers.
Version: Indigo Release
Build id: 20110615-060

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be requested in:

- [bug 302125 - WTP: [content assist] Code assist for ids and classes in CSS](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=302125), and
- [bug 290390 - WTP [content assist] Code assist for url's, colors and fonts](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=290390).

It is not implemented yet, though.

The first bug report points out that is is [implemented in Aptana](https://aptanastudio.tenderapp.com/discussions/questions/266-code-assist-for-ids-and-classes-in-css), so you have this editor ([Aptana studio](http://www.aptana.com/), [based on Eclipse3.5+](http://aptana.org/products/studio3/getting_started) and available as an Eclipse plugin if you want) to consider as an alternative.